# Is it possible to get an expiration date of a subscription?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am using Graph API to fetch Office365 subscriptions. Is it possible to get an expiration date of a subscription ? [SubscribedSku](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/subscribedsku) doesn't have it.

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/subscription

Comment: Well, I believe it's a different type of subscription. I am talking about an Office365 subscription you can buy (like Office 365 Business)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think they put an expiration on the subscription per se.  What expires are licensed features (E3, E5, etc.) based on your billing for each of them (could be monthly, could be annual, whatever).  Azure is the same way - you can get a list of subscriptions but the subscription info doesn't include an expiration value.

BTW - the link in the comment above with an expiration date is for a webhook expiration, not a subscription expiration.  As far as I've seen, all of the Microsoft webhooks provide an expiration value but of course that doesn't help address your question.